# Add leading and trailing slashes to string if needed using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having an issue, where I need to add leading and trailing slashes to string if it's not having them, or do nothing if string is already has it.

For example:

```
"/path" => "/path/"

"path/" => "/path/"

"path" => "/path/"

"/path/" => "/path/"

"/" => "/"

"" => "/"
```

I've tried to use this regular expression, but it's not adding trailing slash:

```
'/path'.replace(/(^\/?)|(\/?$)/, '/'); // output is "/path"
```

Comment: Have a look at [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d262512n/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[With thanks to Dmitry!]

This will work for your first 5 cases:

```
string.replace(/^\/?([^\/]+(?:\/[^\/]+)*)\/?$/, '/$1/');
```

You're then left with the null string, which you can handle using the OR operator (`||`):

```
string.replace(/^\/?([^\/]+(?:\/[^\/]+)*)\/?$/, '/$1/') || '/';
```

**Snippet:**

```js
var RE = /^\/?([^\/]+(?:\/[^\/]+)*)\/?$/;

console.log('/path'.replace(RE, '/$1/') || '/');
console.log('path/'.replace(RE, '/$1/') || '/');
console.log('path'.replace(RE, '/$1/') || '/');
console.log('/path/'.replace(RE, '/$1/') || '/');
console.log('/'.replace(RE, '/$1/') || '/');
console.log(''.replace(RE, '/$1/') || '/');
console.log('path/with/embedded/slashes'.replace(RE, '/$1/') || '/');
```

Comment: Perhaps, the `path` is supposed to have optional slashes in the middle as well. In such cases (e.g. `some/longer/path`) the suggested solution would fail.

Comment: That's a good point.  The OP will have to respond if that's the case.

Comment: Yet, your solution may be extended to [`^\/?([^\/]+(?:\/[^\/]+)*)\/?$`](https://regex101.com/r/SWd8IS/2) to cover such cases.

Comment: @DmitryEgorov correct, it may have optional slashes in the middle. Right now, I've ended up with that solution: `'path'.replace(/^\/?([^\/]+)\/?$/, '/$1/');`. It will return double slashes for an empty and single slash input string. That case could be resolved by simple condition. But it's a little hacky

Comment: @DmitryEgorov, that's brilliant.  Now updated, but if you want to post it yourself for credit, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @RickHitchcock, I only suggested some improvement. And rather a minor one. The main trick of your solution is that `|| '/'`, which I didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter:

```
string.replace(/^\/?([^/]+(?:\/[^/]+)*)\/?$/, '/$1/');
```